# How to change process arguments of build using TFSBuild in command line?

Tags: tfs, build

I have a question about TFSBuild in command line. How can I specify the process arguments ?
As you can see here, I would like to change the Build Definitions list using command line.

[image: Process Arguments]

Is it possible ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the [TFS Chain Build template](https://tfschainbuild.codeplex.com/).

One way to do invoke build from command line is to change the build template to add a string argument called "MSBuidArguments". Use the value of these arguments to get the Build definition collection.

[image]

You can then use the [TFSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) utility with start command to invoke the build, passing the build parameters as command an optional parameter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I'm using TFS Chain Build Template. I will try this and see if it can solve my problem